# What are the performance implications of using multiple world-space UI canvases?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my Unity defense game, each enemy has their HP bar, rendered using a UI slider and a billboard system [as such.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QU6c.jpg)

My concern is that there may be  [too many canvas elements in the scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MKcl.jpg). Is there an alternative option to this, or is my solution effective enough concerning performance??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're not going to have hundreds of enemies on the screen concurrently, you should be fine in terms of performance. You could always introduce an [ObjectPool](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Pool.ObjectPool_1.html) for the [on-screen UI components](https://unity.com/how-to/unity-ui-optimization-tips#:%7E:text=the%20right%20way-,Pool%20UI%20objects%20the%20smart%20way,-Problem%3A%20Pooling%20UI) if you see performance dropping.

I would recommend setting the scale of the Canvas `RectTransform` to something like `0.01` so it occupies less space on the screen. Then re-adjusting the sizing of your existing UI elements to match this scale.

**One Canvas**

Suppose you're looking for an alternative solution for creating world-space UI health bars in Unity. In that case, you could use a single canvas and dynamically change the position of the UI elements within it based on the position of the game objects they are supposed to be attached to.

One way you could achieve this by using the [ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle.html) method of `RectTransformUtility` and converting the world position of the game object to a local position within the canvas. Then, you can use the `rectTransform.anchoredPosition` property to set the position of the UI element within the canvas.

However, there are also drawbacks to using single canvases to display multiple UI elements attached to different game objects. It can cause the canvas to become "dirty," meaning that every frame needs to be redrawn.

Comment: Wow, the perfect answer for me! Thank you a lot!!